# SQL Server and fetch data from system table

Tags: sql-server

When I am designing table then I am putting text in description attribute of all column.

Suppose column name is empid and column description is Employee ID.

So I need to show the data from my table but want to show column name from description attribute which will querying sys table.

How is it possible? Can anyone give me a sample SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the extended property *in addition* to the values from the table (i.e., as another column), but not in lieu of the column name without using dynamic SQL. If you want to simply return the description with the data, you can do something like this:

```
Create Table dbo.Test
    (
    EmpId int not null Primary Key
    , Col1 varchar(10) null
    , Col2 varchar(10) null
    )
Insert dbo.Test( EmpId, Col1, Col2 )
Select 1, 'Foo', 'Bar'
Union All Select 2, 'Gamma', 'Theta'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name = N'MS_Description', 
    @value = N'EmployeeID', 
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = dbo, 
    @level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = Test,
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',  @level2name = EmpId;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name = N'MS_Description', 
    @value = N'Column1', 
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = dbo, 
    @level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = Test,
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',  @level2name = Col1;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name = N'MS_Description', 
    @value = N'Column2', 
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = dbo, 
    @level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = Test,
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',  @level2name = Col2;
GO
Select T.EmpId, ColDesc.Emp1Desc
    , T.Col1, ColDesc.Col1Desc
    , T.Col2, ColDesc.Col2Desc
From Test As T
    Cross Apply (
                Select Min( Case When objname = 'EmpId' Then value End ) As Emp1Desc
                    , Min( Case When objname = 'Col1' Then value End ) As Col1Desc
                    , Min( Case When objname = 'Col2' Then value End ) As Col2Desc
                From fn_listextendedproperty (NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Test', 'column', default)
                ) As ColDesc
```

If you wanted to just pull the descriptions, you can do that like so:

```
Select objname, value As Description
From fn_listextendedproperty (NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Test', 'column', default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [extended properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx)? If so, you can query `sys.extended_properties` (see the previous link for more details).

Comment: yes i am referring extended properties. i got the sql after searching from google. the sql is below which gives column description. SELECT  
    [Table Name] = OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id), 
    [Column Name] = c.name, 
    [Description] = ex.value  
FROM  
    sys.columns c  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    sys.extended_properties ex  
ON  
    ex.major_id = c.object_id 
    AND ex.minor_id = c.column_id  
    AND ex.name = 'MS_Description'  
WHERE  
    OBJECTPROPERTY(c.object_id, 'IsMsShipped')=0  
    AND OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = 'job_flow_state' 
ORDER  
    BY OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id), c.column_id.

Comment: how to use the above sql to show the description in my sql like select empid,empname from emp. i was to show 'employee id' from description field in my sql but i do not want to hard code it rather i wan to fetch description for the column from sys table. please guide me. thanks

Comment: @user728750 - The only way to do that is using dynamic SQL. Thus, it is not recommended. Instead, you should simply query for the descriptions separate from the data and combine them in your middle-tier or presentation tier.